# How can the Microsoft and the Facebook Fibers reach 160 Tbps between Virginia and Bilbao?

Tags: telecommunication, data, fiber-optics

According to [this article](https://www.theverge.com/2017/9/25/16359966/microsoft-facebook-transatlantic-cable-160-terabits-a-second), Microsoft and Facebook have completed a 160 terabits cross-Atlantic cable. Based on my calculations, this doesn't seem probable, so what did I miss in my calculation?

The maximum frequency that a mono-mode fiber can reach is roughly:

$F_{max}=(1/\lambda)*\sqrt{\frac{c}{DL}}$     $(1)$

$D$ is the dispersion parameter.
$L$ its length. 
$\lambda$ is the central wavelength.

For $\lambda$=1500 nm , $D$ = 100 ps/nm/km and $L$ = 10 km.

I find: 10 GHz

Assuming 400 wavelength channels, 2 polarizations,  8 fibers, without relays under the ocean and a bit of magic I cannot reach 160 THz.  What am I missing?

$(1)$ is obtained with the [definition of $D$](https://www.rp-photonics.com/group_velocity_dispersion.html) assuming that the dispersion of a pulse of angular frequency $\omega_0$ , angular line-width width $\delta \omega_0$, duration $\delta \tau_0=2\pi/\delta \omega_0$ is $\delta \tau_1=L(1/Vg(\omega_0+\delta \omega_0 /2)- 1/Vg(\omega_0-\delta \omega_0 /2)=LD\lambda^2/(\delta \tau_0)$. $Vg$ is the group velocity.

The maximum frequency is such that:

$F_{max}=1/\delta \tau_0$

and

$F_{max}=1/\delta \tau_1=\frac{\delta \tau_0}{LD\lambda^2}$

Comment: Good question !